# Universal property about discrete group in C*-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

***Universal property***: Let $u:\Gamma \rightarrow B(H)$ be any unitary representation of $\Gamma$. Then, there is a unique $*-$homomorphism $\pi:C^{*}(\Gamma) \rightarrow B(H)$ such that $\pi_{u}(s)=u_{s}$ for all $s\in \Gamma$. (Here, $\Gamma$ is a discrete group here and the $C^{*}(\Gamma)$ is the *reduced* $C^{*}$-algebra.)

There is a quotation below:

**Let $\Lambda\subset\Gamma$ be a subgroup, then, by universality, there is a canonical $*$-homomorphism $\pi: C^{*}(\Lambda)\rightarrow C^{*}(\Gamma)$.**

In my view, there is a unitary representation: $\Lambda \rightarrow\Gamma\rightarrow B(l^{2}(\Gamma))$ (the first map is inclusion map and the second map is the left regular representation). Then, by universality, we only have a unique $*$-homomorphism $\pi: C^{*}(\Lambda)\rightarrow B(l^{2}(\Gamma))$. **But I do not know how to get a canonical $*$-homomorphism $\pi: C^{*}(\Lambda)\rightarrow C^{*}(\Gamma)$.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do is you think of $C^*(\Gamma)$ as already represented. Then the inclusion $\Lambda\to\Gamma$ is a unitary representation, and you can apply the universality you defined.

Comment: In the universal property, the unitary representation is from a discrete group to $B(H)$, but your unitary representation is just from a discrete group $\Lambda$ to a discrete group $\Gamma$.

Comment: But $\Gamma$, being discrete, is canonically embedded in $C^*(\Gamma) $. And any C$^*$-algebra can be thought represented faithfully in some $B(H) $.

Comment: Yeah, you mean $\Lambda \rightarrow B(H)$ is a unitary representation  $(~\Lambda \rightarrow \Gamma \rightarrow C^{*}(\Gamma)\subseteq B(H)~)$. Then, from universality, we can only get a *-homomorphism $C^{*}(\Lambda) \rightarrow B(H)$, not to $C^{*}(\Gamma)$, Right? Please, forgive my foolish... - -!

Comment: The homomorphism is into $B(H)$, but it maps onto the generators of $C^*(\Gamma)$, so its range is exactly $C^*(\Gamma)$.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I'm not sure why the range is exactly $C^*(\Gamma)$, although I agree the range is contained in $C^*(\Gamma)$. Can you explain please?

Comment: @Shirly: you are right. It is easy to see that it is as you say in the case where  $\Lambda$ is the trivial group.